# How to identify the caller of a (transient) executable?

Tags: linux, command-line, process, c

Is there a generic way to do this? What if the executable is only alive for a fraction of a second and I can't even fire `ps` to catch it? And  the executable is not a script which I can add debug clauses into.

One example case is the following: I was poking around GNOME and watching syslog, for example, sliding the brightness slider and see some executable(`/usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-backlight-helper` in this case) being called to send brightness values to one monitor. I would like the command to send brightness values to all monitors, hence I am trying to find who calls it, ideally the whole chain of events.

Comment: You can use the Linux audit subsystem to capture information about all command executions (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84847/is-there-an-easy-way-to-log-all-commands-executed-including-command-line-argume).