# How do I run command hooks when a specific process is started?

Tags: shell-script, scripting, process, monitoring

Suppose the specific process is a long-running background process A. I wanted to execute a bash script command/script hooks for process A right after process A is started, for example getting its pid and doing something with it. The problem with my use case is that I don't have control over when/how process A is started, and I can't alter process A to generate pidfile; hence the hook idea.

Currently, process A can be run multiple times so there can be multiple pids associated to process A. The script hook should be run on every instance of process A, not just the first run.

I have tried using cron and pgrep to get all the instances of process A. However, there's 60-second latency with this approach since it is the shortest polling interval time with cron.

My questions:

1. What are my options for near real-time notification (< 5-sec latency is acceptable, the lower the better) whenever new process A is started AND execute the bash hook for process A reliably?
2. Is running an infinite while loop + pgrep in the bg with lower latency (eg: 1-5 secs sleep) a safe option?
3. Since inotify exists for file events, is there any similar mechanism for listening (+ running cmd hook) to a specific process event (eg: started/killed/proc status change)?

Thanks!

Comment: What starts the "long running backgtound process A"? Are you an administrator on the machine?

Comment: Once you have the PID, what will you do with "process A"? Will you it once per "process A", or repeatedly. Do you have the support of your SysAdmin AND the owner of "process A"? If we help, will it turn out to have been criminal?

Comment: @icarus imagine a client-server arch where multiple clients can run arbitrary programs on the server. The server don't know when the program will be run by the client (nor what programs will be run by them), but when a certain program is run the server wants to run additional scripts

Comment: @waltinator No, we will not modify Process A. Instead, we have another secure process running on the server that we control (eg: Process B) that provides data for other processes. In order for any process to access the data, they need to be authenticated with Process B which utilizes the proc PID. So in this case, we want to authenticate all instances of Process A runs (cos they can be run multiple times with different PIDs) with Process B.

Comment: @icarus Yes, we're the admin of the server machine (where Process A is run) but not the admin of the client machines. Process A is a process that we can't modify and can't know when they start as it is triggered from the client-side, but the server has control over stopping them.

Comment: "Process Ais a process we can't modify" - not even to rename the program that is being run and put a wrapper in it's place?

Comment: @icarus No, Process A is Proprietary software that we can't modify. Although, I wonder if it's possible to attach a process hook/alias that can capture the original cmd so that when Process A is run we can run additional scripts without altering how the original command is run?

Comment: Even proprietary software exists in files, and you can rename files and create new wrapper scripts with the original names. Having said that, if process A is started from process Z by just using "fork" but no "exec" then you have a point. However this would be unusual!

Comment: Ah yes, Process A is forked from proprietary software and not directly executed by the client.

Answer (score 1):

The only reliable solution is to arrange to run the program via a wrapper script. There are many different ways to do that, and it's unusual for none of them to apply.

- Configure or modify the program(s) that call this program to run your wrapper instead.
- Put a wrapper by the same name ahead of the real program in the `$PATH`.
- Rename the program and give the wrapper its original name.

This approach guarantees that your wrapper will run, and it gets the opportunity to prepare before running the real program if necessary. The wrapper also gets the ability to be the parent process of the real program, which lets it reliably be notified when it dies and obtain its exit status.

You can use [LoggedFS](https://rflament.github.io/loggedfs/) to monitor events on a filesystem. See [LoggedFS configuration file syntax](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13794/loggedfs-configuration-file-syntax) for documentation on its configuration file. Point `loggedfs` to the directory containing the executable. Note that you need to own it or run loggedfs as root. Each time a file is executed, there is an `open` event, and you get the PID of the process. Note that there is also an `open` event if the file is opened for reading; I don't think you can distinguish execute events specifically with LoggedFS alone. When the process exits, there is a `release` event. Note that by the time your monitoring code runs, the process might have already died.

Under Linux, you can use [inotifywait](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/inotifywait.1.html) to wait for an `access` or `close_nowrite` event on the executable, e.g. `inotifywait -m -e access,close_nowrite --format=%e /bin/ls`. There is an `access` event whenever the file is executed and a `close_nowrite` when the process dies. You can't get the process ID that way, so you'll then have to find out which processes have the file open (e.g. with `fuser` or `lsof`) and then filter the ones that are executing the file.

Linux also has a more precise facility that lets you monitor events such as the execution of a specific file and reports the PID that caused the event: the audit subsystem. See [Is there an easy way to log all commands executed, including command line arguments?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84847/is-there-an-easy-way-to-log-all-commands-executed-including-command-line-argume/84854#84854). You can then use [audispd](https://doc.opensuse.org/documentation/leap/archive/15.0/security/html/book.security/cha.audit.comp.html#sec.audit.audisp) to run a custom program when the audit event occurs. All this requires being root, though, and if you were root then presumably you could replace the executable and you wouldn't need this.